# How to type deeply nested objects with typescript?

Tags: typescript

I get product data via API, the data is deeply nested, properties might change according to the product definition. Do I need to fully type the product data in order to use typescript correctly? Or how would you approach deeply nested data in the frontend?

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBABwE5gCYFcTwLxwN7BxwCWqAXHAIwA0hc4ANmElBQNoBESApqh9XA4BzHtwgcAurSLgAtrLExWcCOgYNpcAG4BDJMR0Ql7OkQJELJclU2WIOhRQ4wAtFAAWxJDH5xTFuQUjZVV1WwtZHRhufR0GE0tLc0TLUgoafxT7R0FwGBhIfkzEwMVlTgAJbnUwOAB1ZgY+KRTLYqIAX2KJfy6iHq7gADN0CCxiSDghbhgABRQMLAAeABUAPgAKZDRMGAoVgEp8Oh4YdCQIRAXd4EGRsZgJy6gZ+Z2sADEvWAA1PQMjABhMDyRSrTbbRZ7OArASlIwUWD6CBCI7JSG7AB0uliwTYAAYJJj4Uo4Lg2CSekRTudLhisLcgA)

```
const product = {
  id: 1,
  colors: ["red", "green"],
  comments: null,
  variants: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "t-shirt", 
      comments: null,
      material: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "cotton",
          comments: ["Hello World"],          
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

function getProduct<T>(product: T) {
  return product
}
```

**Property 'variants' does not exist on type 'T'.**

```
function setProductFirstVariantComment<T>(product: T, comment: string) {
  product.variants[0].comments = [comment] // TS ERROR
  return product
}
```

Comment: You need to use appropriate constraint. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/WJy1gm) . However, may I ask, why do you return `product` and in the same time mutate it. As per my understanding, if you want to retyrn new product, you should return new reference or, if you mutate product, you should not return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is a type-strict language, so you need to define types to map with your data.

Without types, the compiler cannot understand which type/data you refer to. In your case, `product` is a generic type `T` but the compiler does not know what is `T` in your context because you never define it anywhere.

You should map your data with proper types like below

```
type Material = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  comments: string[] | null,
}

type Variant = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  comments: string[] | null,
  material: Material[]
}

type Product = {
  id: number,
  colors: string[],
  comments: string[] | null,
  variants: Variant[]
}

const productData: Product = {
  id: 1,
  colors: ["red", "green"],
  comments: null,
  variants: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "t-shirt", 
      comments: null,
      material: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "cotton",
          comments: ["Hello World"],          
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

function getProduct<T>(product: T) {
  return product
}

//define T which extends Product type
function setProductFirstVariantComment<T extends Product>(product: T, comment: string) {
  product.variants[0].comments = [comment]
  return product
}

setProductFirstVariantComment(productData, "new")
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghsCAnAlnANlAvFA3gKCihQBMAuKAOwFcBbAI2QBpCq5aIKBnYVSgcxZEAxgHtaHSsC7deKAQG0AulAA%20VaunQsAvvnyhIUAGpxUcKdjytSFGg2atK7TlB59BrMRIhSZbuUUVdRotIShaBGQ0dAp4RHN0ZXw9A3BoAAUkURJqYWArAiJbDQckcLF0USR-d3l%20ZQrxSWlZD2U1DTDWADczND8KU3MpZNSxSh4oMGzc-IARBDgKLJy8gpwi4nIoAEYmqpqKBQAiJAgSE6YoE-5z3xOlJp9Bru1e-otWqAVWIi2iMUdvs-oDnBwKCdgABaLgACxQSGAVygoJEzV831C70BgMiCRixzRgIBuMBJRBZLJ4NcJzEwGAokoV2JuO8LX8pwAEhAtKIoAB1aroS5PKm41lQPRUpSg6VQWWpABm1Eo%20RQTKg-AgwFWc2AAB4ACoAPgAFDM1vkKEaAJTWIjnYDUJCUaazdYpfQAem9JAgSvk0CNUAA7gjhHCoBAAB6ISgkLhQPXrKCGCD4FVq4Aat1cHUp-IAMURPGGA2AAGEMVJjdG475E8mPflzZb9TbruzMW16vatu31gA6PojaQKAAMSiH3b8VgUs%20AssdOpdbsH%20S9%20HzupbwBLNWA5a%201ZewAte8WwDg1xOlAgoZOtqAA)